# How do I organize my controllers in directories but still get benefits of REST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

## Context & Background

I have a resource called `Stock`, which represents the stock of a company. That model & schema looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: stocks
#
#  id         :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  ticker     :string
#  name       :string
#  price      :float
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  jse_link   :string
#

class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :port_stocks
  validates :ticker, :price, presence: true
end
```

I then have a `User` model, and a `Portfolio` model. Each `User has_one: portfolio`.

I also have a `PortStock` model, which is basically the instance of each stock that each `user` has in their `portfolio`. i.e. even though the system has information on stock `ABC` (company name, ticker, price, etc.), each user will buy that stock at a different price, and buy different amounts of units of each stock so the value of the position each user has on stock `ABC` will be different....hence the need for a new model -- `PortStock`.

That being said, each `Portfolio has_many :port_stocks`.

## Problem

My core problem is trying to figure out how to model buying and selling of a `PortStock`, since the business rules are different.

When a user buys a `PortStock`, that is straight forward. They simply choose the stock they want to buy, enter the number of units, the price they want to buy it at, etc. We then create a new record of a `PortStock`.

The tricky part is, selling a `PortStock`. The following things have to be considered:

1. The user has to currently own the `PortStock`.
2. The user can only sell up to a maximum number of `PortStock` units they own.
3. Selling a `PortStock` doesn't mean simply 'deleting' a previously `bought PortStock`. It involves creating another record.
4. This new `sell` record, relates to one (or more) of the other `buy` records of this stock. i.e. say user A owns 1,000 units of `ABC`, and they want to sell 500 units of `ABC`, 500 units are still left (i.e. the original 1,000 needs to be modified to be 500).

So I am having a hard time modeling this & getting my controllers correct.

This is what my `PortStock` model looks like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: port_stocks
#
#  id             :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  portfolio_id   :integer
#  stock_id       :integer
#  volume         :integer
#  purchase_price :float
#  current_price  :float
#  percent_change :float
#  created_at     :datetime         not null
#  updated_at     :datetime         not null
#  current_value  :float
#  dollar_change  :float
#  total_spend    :float
#  bought_on      :datetime
#  action         :integer
#  position       :integer          default("open")
#

class PortStock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :portfolio
  belongs_to :stock

  enum action: [ :buy, :sell ]
  enum position: [ :open, :closed ]
end
```

In an attempt to streamline everything, I was trying to not just have `PortStock#Sell` and `PortStock#Buy` actions in my `PortStock` controller, so I tried to put everything in `app/controllers/port_stocks/`, e.g. `app/controllers/port_stocks/buy_controller.rb` and `app/controllers/port_stocks/sell_controller.rb`.

Within each, I created `_form.html.erb`, `new.html.erb` and `create.html.erb` files, to leverage REST.

So, in my routes, I did this:

```
  resources :port_stocks do
    scope module: 'port_stocks' do
      resources :buy
      resources :sell
    end
  end
```

This generates the following `new` route:

```
new_port_stock_buy_path GET /port_stocks/:port_stock_id/buy/new(.:format)   port_stocks/buy#new
```

Note the `:port_stock_id` in the URL.

But this isn't work properly for me yet. It all feels very confusing in my head, and doesn't feel like it is laid out properly.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t appear that you are using the `stocks` resource for anything more than a namespace, so I would propose doing just that:

```
namespace :stocks do
  resources :buy
  resources :sell
end
```

In trying to stay RESTful, I don’t love your `buy` or `sell` resources as those are verbs rather than nouns (reaources are nouns;  then you have RESTful actions or verbs on them). maybe `:buy_order`.  What is the model they line up to? Might be worth a bit more thought before you memorialize these controllers.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by anything other than a namespace. I am using it as a model. Each user can buy or sell stocks as needed. I do agree that a bit more thought may be needed, so I would appreciate some more probing to get to the right architecture.

Comment: Hmm, now I’m confused at what you might be trying to do.  Maybe you could post your stocks model (and schematic) along with the stocks controller so we can better see what you are trying to do.

Comment: So I was trying to just keep the question to be as simple as possible, but since you asked for more info, I decided to just give you the full hundred. The key thing to note here is that in my original question, I only spoke about `Stock`. That was a bit misleading given the context of my app. What I really wanted help with is `PortStock`, but I figured that would be too tricky to understand simply without the full explanation so I gave you the simple version. That being said, I have now revised the entire question to be more thorough. Let me know if you have any questions.